# Is «le imitó» an example of «leísmo» and is it only considered correct usage in Spain?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

**Primero mi pregunta en español:**

¿Es «le imitó» un ejemplo de [**«leísmo»**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo)?

I recently came across the phrase "He imitated him," in English and wondered how best to say it in Spanish.  Initially, I thought

**«Lo imitó»**

would be best, but wanted to be sure.  When I discovered that Google's Ngram showed a fair number of "Le imitó," as you can see in the image below:

[image]

it left me with questions:

1. If I am trying to say, "He imitated him," must I use «Le imitó», or only if I am in Spain?
2. Do Spaniards use both «Lo imitó» and «Le imitó» to mean "He imitated  him?" or is the one (the former) used strictly to mean "He imitated it," and the other (the latter) to mean "He imitated him?"
3. Will I find the use of «Le imitó» any place other than Spain?

**Detalles en español:**

Recientemente me encontré la frase "He imitated him," y me preguntaba qué sería la mejor manera de decirla en español.  Inicialmente, pensé

**«Lo imitó»**

sería mejor, pero quería estar segura.  Cuando descubrí que Google Ngram mostró un número considerable de «Le imitó», (véanse arriba en la sección inglesa) me dejó con preguntas:

1. Si estoy tratando de decir "He imitated him," ¿debo usar «Le imitó», o sólo si estoy en España?
2. ¿Los españoles usan tanto «Lo imitó» como «Le imitó» para significar "He imitated him?" o es la una (la primera frase) sólo para significar "He imitated it," y la otra (la segunda frase) sólo para significar "He imitated him?"
3. ¿Voy a encontrar el uso de «Le imitó» en lugares aparte de España?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás en lo cierto en la mayoría de casos.

En efecto lo más correcto (al menos para mí) será siempre decir `"lo imitó"`, porque es complemento directo. Sería diferente si fuera complemento indirecto, por ejemplo en `"le imitó esa forma de hablar tan graciosa y estaba detrás"`.

No obstante la RAE acepta el uso de "le" en estos casos, es decir, que puedes utilizar "le" en lugar de "lo" (sólo cuando es persona, y masculino).

Por supuesto esto se aceptó porque es ya misión imposible luchar contra corriente. Tristemente la mayoría de gente piensa que "le" es para personas y "lo" es para objetos, independientemente de si es CD o CI. Sin embargo esto es "normal" si se habla sin analizar por qué las cosas son así, ya que en la mayoría de oraciones el CD es un objeto y el CI una persona.

Así que, respondiendo a tu pregunta:

1) Puedes usar ambas, pero es mejor usar "lo". En España también (de hecho, te invito a que uses "lo" para "acostumbrar" a la gente jeje), pero por poder, puedes usar ambos.

2) Creo que has puesto lo mismo en ambas. En cualquier caso, las dos significan lo mismo porque ahora se acepta "le".

3) Por el motivo expuesto antes, es probable que el leísmo se extienda. Sin embargo, en la mayor parte de hispanoamérica el leísmo no está extendido.

Comment: Aunque me beneficié de mucho que fue escrito en este hilo, voy a dar la marca verde a ti.  ¿Por qué?  Pues, hiciste dos cosas que ayudó mucho para aclarar cierta confusión que existió en mi mente: 1) Escribiste: Tristemente la mayoría de gente piensa que "le" es para personas y "lo" es para objetos, independientemente de si es CD o CI y 2) Abordaste las preguntas específicas que tuve, línea por línea.  La respuesta de Guifa es muy meritoria también.  De hecho, todas son buenas, pero sólo puedo conceder una marca verde, y voy a concederla a ti.  Te agradezco y agradezco a todos.

Answer (score 4):

Un problema con la búsqueda que hiciste en Google es que la locución «le imitó» *puede* ser un caso de leísmo, si es que el pronombre se deba interpretar como pronombre átono directo.  No obstante, es también perfectamente posible que el verbo *imitar* tome un complemento indirecto también, el cual aparecería después del verbo (*le imitó la voz*) y así se incluiría en aquellos resultados.  Por eso, no podemos decir nada basándonos en ellos.

Algunos verbos a lo largo del tiempo también han vacilado un poco entre el tipo de complemento que usan (especialmente los verbos de percepción).  Que sepa yo, *imitar* no es uno de esos , ni se considera un verbo de afección psicológica que admite tanto complementos directos como indirectos sin distinción, pero sería interesante investigar si hoy es más frecuente decir que se imite directamente a algo o alguien y que antes se imitase algún aspecto de otra cosa (lo cual favorecería el uso de *le*).  Por las razones que ya mencioné, nos obligaría contar individualmente y no lo podríamos hacer informáticamente (a menos que los sustantivos y pronombres estuviesen ya etiqueteados por su papel en la oración).

Con respeto a la extensión del uso de *le* como pronombre directo, se puede usar *le* como complemento directo sin problema en varias áreas fuera de España, pero con un significado ligeramente diferente: se puede usar cuando el referente es *usted* (y también *les* cuando *ustedes*), sea femenino o masculino, en el llamado *leísmo de cortesía*.  Tal leísmo está extendido en muchas partes del mundo hispanohablante.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando es complemento directo, lo correcto es LO, sin embargo se acepta LE solamente cuando el referente es masculino.

> ¿Has visto a **Juan**? Sí, **lo** vi ayer. / Sí, **le** vi ayer.
>   ¿Has visto a **Juan y a los niños**? Sí, **los** he visto en el parque.
>   Compré la medicina y se **la** di sin que nadie me viera.
>   ¿Has recogido a **las niñas**? Sí, **las** recogí antes de ir al taller.

Si el complemento es indirecto, siempre se usa LE, independiente del género.

> **Le** pedí disculpas a mi **madre**.
>   **Le** dije a su **hermana** que viniera.
>   **Les** di un regalo a los **niños**.

Más información aquí: [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo)